# Dynamically create a forum in Drupal, and link to it on a node?

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7

I am building a site for a client in Drupal 7.  Unfortunately I have to be careful here about what I say due to non-disclosure agreement so apologies for the vagueness...

We make use of externally provided paid-for content in iframes throughout the site.

Some of this content are links, which when clicked open a new page in our site, dynamically filling this page with information, within another iframe.  Let's call this page the Company Data page, and each time it's loaded it shows data from a specific company.

My client now wants forums on the site, and threads which are specific to each of those companies. He wants these threads linked to from the Company Data page.

So I have the following questions:

1. is it possible to dynamically create a new forum thread for each company?  This could be done (and probably should ONLY be done) when someone first clicks a link for that particular company.  (I guess this means that when someone first clicks on Company A's link, a forum thread is created for Company A, as well as the user being taken to the Company Data page for Company A.)
2. is it then possible to have a link to that forum (or a block with the forum thread) appear on the dynamically created Company Data page?

I'm totally stuck on this one!